# Is a bounded Operator $T\colon X\to Y$ which satisfies $\beta\lVert x\rVert\leq\lVert Tx\rVert$ for some $\beta > 0$ and all $x\in X$ an isometry?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, isometry

The following question came to when reading L.C.Evans' proof of the Lax-Milgram theorem in his well-known PDE book. However it has nothing to do with PDEs at all but is pure functional-analysis:

Let $X$, $Y$ normed spaces and $T\colon X\to Y$ a bounded linear operator. In addition to the boundedness which means
\begin{equation*}
\exists\alpha > 0\,\forall x\in X\colon\qquad \lVert Tx\rVert\leq \alpha\lVert x\rVert
\end{equation*}
we also want the operator to satisfy the following estimate:
\begin{equation*}
\exists\beta > 0\,\forall x\in X\colon\qquad\beta\lVert x\rVert\leq\lVert Tx\rVert.
\end{equation*}
The question is now: Can we conclude that $T$ is an isometry, i.e. $\lVert Tx\rVert = \lVert x\rVert$ for all $x\in X$?

If not, can we make the conclusion come true by requiring stronger assumptions, e.g. $T$ being bijective or $X$, $Y$ being Banach, etc.?

Comment: $Tx=2x$ satisfies the criteria but is not an isometry.

Comment: Hard to know what direction you are going in here. The stated condition implies that $T$ is one-to-one.  If $T$ has closed range $R$ (which holds for example if $T$ is surjective), the desired condition follows from the fact that the inverse map $R \to X$ is also bounded, by standard but perhaps not quite obvious theorems in functional analysis.

Comment: This inequality implies that $T$ has closed range.

Comment: Thanks @Loobear23 for your counter example! Sometimes I fail to think of the simplest situations.

Comment: @leslietownes can you elaborate on which standard theorems you refer to? 
also another question: The Implication $R(T) \text{ closed}\implies T^{-1}\colon R(T)\to X\text{ bounded}$ is only true if you assume $X$ and $Y$ to be Banach spaces, right? At least I have learned this as a corollary of the bounded inverse theorem which only holds for Banach spaces.